# Jech's proof that $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_\alpha^+$ when $V=L[A]$ for $A\subset P(\omega_\alpha)$

Tags: set-theory

This is a proof I thought I understood some time ago, but on closer inspection I'm not quite able to clinch. It is theorem 19.2 on pg 339 of Jech's *Set Theory*.

> *Theorem.* If $V=L[A]$ and $A\subseteq P(\omega_\alpha)$ then $2^{\aleph_\alpha}=\aleph_{\alpha+1}$
>
> *Proof.* Let $X\subseteq\omega_\alpha.$ Will show that $X\in L_{\omega_{\alpha+1}}[A],$ from which the result follows. Choose $\lambda$ so that $X,A\in L_\lambda[A].$ Then there is a $M\prec L_{\lambda}[A]$ such that $|M|=\aleph_\alpha$ and $\omega_\alpha\cup\{X,A\}\subseteq M.$ Let $N=\pi(M)$ be the transitive collapse.
>
> We have $\pi(Z) = Z$ for every $Z\in P(\omega_\alpha)\cap M,$ and in particular, $\pi(X)= X.$ Also, $\fbox{$\pi(A)=\pi(A\cap M) = A\cap N$.}$ Thus, by condensation, for some $\beta < \omega_\alpha,$ $N = L_\beta[\pi(A)]=L_\beta[A\cap N],$ and so $N=L_\beta[A].$ So since $X=\pi(X)\in N,$ $X\in L_{\omega_{\alpha+1}}[A].$

I get everything except the part I boxed. Since $\pi(Z)= Z$ for any $Z\in A\cap M,$ $\pi(A) = \pi(A\cap M) = A\cap M.$ Then, it's clear that $A\cap M = \pi(A\cap M) \subseteq A\cap N,$ but I don't see how we can show $A\cap N\subseteq A\cap M.$

Let's simplify things by taking $\alpha=0$. What's to preclude the following situation:

We have $x\in M$ and $x\cap M\in A\subseteq P(\omega),$ but $x\setminus \omega\ne 0.$ Then $\pi(x) = x\cap M\in A\cap N$, but $\pi(x)\notin M,$ since if $x\cap M\in M$ then by extensionality in $M$, we would have $x=x\cap M.$

Feel like I must be missing something obvious...

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really make a red part in the proof. My suggestion is boldface, underline, fbox, or if colour is a must, blue $\gg$ red.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for the suggestion, I boxed it instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that the preimage of $P(\omega_\alpha)\cap N$ by $\pi$ is exactly $P(\omega_\alpha) \cap M$.

To see why, let $Z$ be any element of $M$. Using the fact that $\pi(\omega_\alpha) = \omega_\alpha$, along with elementarity of $\pi$ and the inclusion of $M$ into $L_\gamma[A]$ and the fact that $N$ and $L_\gamma[A]$ are transitive, we have
\begin{align}
\pi(Z) \subseteq \omega_\alpha &\iff \pi(Z) \subseteq \pi(\omega_\alpha)\\
&\iff N \vDash \pi(Z) \subseteq \pi(\omega_\alpha)\\
&\iff M \vDash Z \subseteq \omega_\alpha\\
&\iff L_\gamma[A] \vDash Z \subseteq \omega_\alpha\\
&\iff Z \subseteq \omega_\alpha.
\end{align}

What precludes the situation you describe is the fact that $M$ is an elementary substructure of $L_\gamma[A]$ and $L_\gamma[A]$ knows whether $x$ is really a subset of $\omega$.

Comment: Regarding the last part, I agree that kills the situation I describe... $M$ thinks $x\subseteq \omega$ but a transitive model knows better. Regarding the proof, I'll go through it tomorrow, but one question jumps out at me at a glance: how do we know $\pi(Z)\in M$?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen sorry, I had a typo in my answer. I mixed up $M$ and $N$ at one point. It suffices to assume $Z$ is an element of $M$ and then prove that $\pi(Z) \subseteq \omega_\alpha$ if and only if $Z \subseteq \omega_\alpha$ because $\pi$ is a bijection.